# Using the quadratic function to make a prediction

Tags: matrices, quadratics

I've been given a simple problem: use the quadratic
function to predict the number of
subscribers expected in 2010.

According to the table, 
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|} 
 \hline \text{Year} & \text{Subscribers (millions)} \\ \hline
1985 & 1 \\ \hline
 1990 & 11 \\ \hline
2000 & 741\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

I was told to set-up the series of equations like $$A(1985^2) + B(1985) + C = 1$$and so on. However, when I do that and put them in a matrix to solve, I get an answer that is far from correct. Any help in getting me on the right track? I don't know why I'm struggling with this so much... That said, I do suspect I was not told how to set-up this problem correctly.

Answer (score 1):

did you try the system ...

$$A(1985^2) + B(1985) + C = 1 \tag 1   $$

$$A(1990^2) + B(1990) + C = 11 \tag 2 $$

$$A(2000^2) + B(2000) + C = 741 \tag 3 $$

$$ (2)-(1) \implies A(1990^2-1985^2) +5B = 10  \tag 4$$

$$ (3)-(1) \implies A(2000^2-1985^2) +15B = 740 \tag 5$$

now the equation generated from $(5)-3\times (4)$ can be solved for A , sub  into (4) and (1) to get B and C

Comment: Yes (first line should equal 1, my bad), and I get: A=2, B=710, and C=1. That produces a total number of subscribers far less than in the year 2000.

Answer (score 1):

To simplify things we take $1985$ as the origin of time. Let's determine the quadratic function $f(t) = at^2 + bt + c$ such that $f(0) = 1$, $f(5) = 11$ and $f(15) = 741$.
Its coefficients $a$, $b$ and $c$ verify
$$
\left\{
  \begin{alignedat}{4}
    c &= 1 & \quad (1)\\
    25a {}+{} 5b &= 10 & \quad (2) \\
    225a {}+{} 15b &= 740. & \quad (3)
   \end{alignedat}
\right.
$$
Doing $(3) - 3\times (2)$ gives $a = 71/15$, and $(3) - 9\times (2)$ gives $b = -65/3$. Thus
$$
  f(t) = \frac{71}{15} t^2 - \frac{65}{3} t + 1.
$$

Comment: Same answer at almost same time !! By the way, where are you in Toulouse ? I am just next door to you. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Quartier des Carmes, five minutes walk from place du Capitole. Have a good day !

Comment: What are you doing ? University ?

Answer (score 1):

If we name $S$ the number of subscribers and $Y$ the year, you are asked to find $A,B,C$ in the model $$S=A\,Y^2+B\,Y+C$$ and use the values in the table to find the coefficients.

To avoid problems with large numbers, you could rewrite the model as  $$S=A\,t^2+B\,t+C$$ where $t=Y-1985$. In such a case, using the same idea as WW1, the equations write $$A (0^2)+B(0)+C=1$$  $$A (5^2)+B(5)+C=11$$ $$A (15^2)+B(15)+C=741$$ which is much simpler to solve (in particular thanks to the first equation).

Solve for $A,B,C$ and compute the value of the expression for $t=2010-1985=25$.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: Sincere thanks to both you and @Éric-guirbal. I think I see where I went wrong.

Comment: You are very welcome !